# Prevent double-clicking on thumbnail to make sure the content is not loaded twice via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, click, bind, unbind

I have a jquery function that loads post content when I click on the post thumbnail and it works great. But if I click twice, the content gets loaded twice.

I read somewhere that I needed to unbind the click and bind it back when content has finished loading. Here is my attempt.

Now it seems that the `event.preventDefault();` get deactivated or something because it loads the complete page on the second click (instead of the AJAX content).

```
$("a.ajaxed").on("click",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = this,
   // ...; other variables
    $(self).unbind("click"); // code line added 1of2
    $("#streamwrapper").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: ({
                action : "get_all_images",
                post_id: postid
                }),
            success:function(data){
                $("#board").append(postdiv);
                $("#post-container").append(data);
                postdiv.fadeIn(1000);
                $(self).bind("click"); // code line added 2of2
            },
            error:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Have you tried the one() method?

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: one() can be used.. But what if he wants to use the click for the next request again.. I think he can again associate it with the .one event again

Comment: I would go with preventing the ajax request instead of binding and unbinding events. Should be much easier to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I always do is attach an 'executing' flag to the element using `$(this).data`. The function first checks to see if this flag is set, if it is it returns out, otherwise it sets the flag and clears it on success. The following should do what you want:

```
$("a.ajaxed").on("click",function(event) {
   // ...; other variables

   var self = this; // needed for $(self).removeData below

   if ($(self).data('executing')) // if we're executing, return
       return;

    $(self).data('executing', true); // set executing flag

    $("#streamwrapper").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: ({
                action : "get_all_images",
                post_id: postid
                }),
            success:function(data){
                $("#board").append(postdiv);
                $("#post-container").append(data);
                postdiv.fadeIn(1000);

                $(self).removeData('executing'); // clear the executing flag
            },
            error:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Hoff I've accepted the answer but you should use a var `self = this,` and use `$(self)` instead of `$(this)` everywhere in the function or else the removeData won't work.

Comment: Ohhh good catch, I was wondering why you had that and thought it was unnecessary so I removed it. But now I see that `$(this).removeData` would refer to `$('#steamwrapper')`. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can actually try using the beforeSend and complete events to bind and unbind the events.. This makes sure that the button has no event as soon as Ajax is sent..

```
var clickEvent = 
    $("a.ajaxed").on("click",function(event) {
    var self = this,

    $("#streamwrapper").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: ({
                action : "get_all_images",
                post_id: postid
                }),
            success:function(data){
                $("#board").append(postdiv);
                $("#post-container").append(data);
                postdiv.fadeIn(1000);
            },
            error:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
            $(self).unbind("click"); // code line added 1of2
            }, 
            complete: function() {
                clickEvent();
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```